# Right click in KDE opens the file and the context menu at the same time on the Desktop in Folder view

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I have problem in KDE. Every time I want just to right click to show the menu it opens the file and shows the menu. This is only on my desktop that loads Location:Desktop. This never happens in dolphin. (Tested for the same folder Desktop)

[image]
[image]

- 4.4.0-78-generic
- Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Release: 16.04
- Codename:    xenial
- KDE Plasma version 5.5.5

The system is configured to open files and folders on single click, but not on right single click :)
Looks to me like the context menu opens very fast and when I release the right button it clicks on the first option from the context menu that is 'Open'

How can I fix that. Thanks

Comment: Is your mouse button sound? I mean mouse can go crazy very easily.

Comment: No, is not. I think the problem is similar to this problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33519/how-to-make-x-less-sensitive-when-right-clicking and I tried the @Johans answer but it didn't work completely. May be I cannot set them properly.

Comment: Oops. I've booted to the 17.04 where I don't have KDE installed. Can you check the shortcuts Desktop configuration -> Mouse action -> Right click?

Comment: There is not 'Mouse' menu it the Desktop behavior. In the main menu settings there is section 'Input devices' and there is menu 'Mouse'